# Activator Crashes on combobox set autocomplete mode

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, activator

i need to instantiate forms using activator because i need to iterate all form's controls to set a property. For this procedure i'm using the code below.

```
using (Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type))
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Program.connectionString))
                        {

                            cn.Open();
                            General.ProcessControls(cn, frm, frm.GetType().Name);
                            cn.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

All good till here. The code above runs like a charm for all forms except one in which i have a combobox with autocomplete mode setted in SuggestAppend mode. In this form my application crashes with InvocationTargetException into function InitializeComponent() when it tries to set the autocomplete mode. Below there is the line of code where my application crashes.

```
 this.comboBoxAreaType.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.comboBoxAreaType.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the inner exception of the TargetInvocationException?

Comment: What thread is running `Activator.CreateInstance`?  Is it the main UI thread? (The green one in Visual Studio's Threads window).

Comment: A) The inner exception is "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."  B) The procedure which do all this job runs in a seperate thread not in the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agent-j your comments was very helpfull to understand what is going wrong.

I add the command bellow to set my thread to STA AppartmentState just before the call of thread start() and now it works like a charm.

```
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```